# How can I avoid strange pattern in the footer on the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css

I have a problem with the site http://www.domda.se which is only present on iphone, not on desktop. I think it has to do with some scripts in the footer which have display:none applied. Can I be right or am I totally wrong? Thankful for help in this mysterious matter. 
(Tried to append a screenshot but unfortunately I'm not able to post pictures yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you see is the tiny smiley that you also notice on the desktop version on the bottom left.

The smiley listens to your responsive css in the mediaqueries:

```
body img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and stretches to 100%, creating the pattern. Add something like

```
#wpstats {
  width: auto;
}
```

to override this 100% stretching for the smiley.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you so much. It was kind of a fun problem. :)